# How to display a loading progress bar when jQuery function is executing?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, progress-bar

We want to show a loading progress bar when jQuery code is being executed, however the progress bar is shown after the jQuery code has executed.

```
<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#loading').hide();
});

$("[id*=btnAddCa_Cl]").click(function() {

  var ttlCationCaco3 = $("input[id$='txtTdsAdjustmentForCation']").val();
  if (parseFloat(ttlCationCaco3) > 0) {
    $("input[id$='txtCalciumPpmAsCaCO3']").val(parseFloat($("input[id$='txtTdsAdjustmentForCation']").val()) + parseFloat($("input[id$='txtCalciumPpmAsCaCO3']").val()));
    $("input[id$='txtCalciumPpmAsCaCO3']").trigger('keyup');
  } else {
    $("input[id$='txtChloridePpmAsCaCO3']").val(parseFloat($("input[id$='txtTdsAdjustmentForAnion']").val()) + parseFloat($("input[id$='txtChloridePpmAsCaCO3']").val()));
    $("input[id$='txtChloridePpmAsCaCO3']").trigger('keyup');
  }

});
```

Comment: The JS code you've shown doesn't seem to do anything with the progress bar, except hide it on load...? Also, unless you're making a lengthy async operation (ie. 1 second+) a loading bar is rather moot.

Comment: What you're asking still makes no sense.  There is no "jquery function executing" and your image still shows when the page loads.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068461/how-to-call-loading-progress-bar-when-jquery-is-executing

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the values are getting calculated on the jquery event of button click. It takes more than 30-40 secs to calculate as it involves calculating values for 15-20 text boxes using various formulae

Comment: also the link given by @freedomn-m is not actually useful. I have tried doing that as well.

Comment: How complex are the calculations? I can't imagine anything taking 30-40 seconds for 15 boxes. I'd argue that you should be looking to optimise that code if it's taking that long. A progress bar is not the solution.

Comment: Also, do you mean that you just want to show a single loading spinner graphic ***or*** a progress bar? The two are very different things.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The calculations are related to chemistry with log, power, etc. so it takes time.Also i want a single loading graphic spinner

Comment: Welcome to SO. The code you have shown does not seem to have anything to do with the question you describe.  You'll get a better response here if you edit and clarify.  As it is, it is likely to be closed as unclear.

Comment: Out of curiosity I'd be interested to see an example of the calculations to see if they can be optimised in JS, but I've added an answer for you with a workaround solution.

Comment: The link above is to an *identical* question, word for word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments under the question it appears that you want the loading spinner graphic (note: not a progress bar, the two are *very* different in behaviour) to appear while your long-running chemistry-related calculations run.

The issue you have here is that the calculations are a synchronous process and prevent the DOM from being updated while they are in process. To fix this you could place the calculation logic inside a timeout with a very short delay in order to give the DOM some time to update and not block the UI from being amended. As such, try this:

```js
let $loading = $('#loading');
let $calcPpmAsCao3 = $("input[id$='txtCalciumPpmAsCaCO3']");
let $chloridePpmAsCao3 = $("input[id$='txtChloridePpmAsCaCO3']");

let ttlCationCaco3 = parseFloat($("input[id$='txtTdsAdjustmentForCation']").val());
let ttlAnionCaco3 = parseFloat($("input[id$='txtTdsAdjustmentForAnion']").val());


$("[id*=btnAddCa_Cl]").click(function() {
  $loading.show();

  setTimeout(function() {
    // calculation logic here \/ \/ \/        

    if (ttlCationCaco3 > 0) {
      $calcPpmAsCao3.val(function(i, v) {
        return parseFloat(this.value) + ttlCationCaco3;
      }).trigger('keyup');
    } else {
      $chloridePpmAsCao3.val(function(i, v) {
        return parseFloat(this.value) + ttlAnionCaco3;
      }).trigger('keyup');
    }

    // calculation logic here /\ /\ /\        

    $loading.hide();
  }, 10);
});
```

```css
#loading {
  display: none;
}
```

There's a couple of things to note in this example. Firstly accessing the DOM is one of (relatively) slowest things you can do in JS. As such it's worth taking steps to reduce the number of times you do it. If you need to refer to an element multiple times, 'cache' it in a variable.

Also, call `parseFloat()` on a value once and store it in a variable. Then you don't need to keep calling `parseFloat()` on something which you already had access to.

Lastly, I used CSS to hide `#loading` by default. Don't do this in JS as the element will be visible for a split second before the JS runs and hides it. CSS executes first and is quicker, so it avoids this issue.

Comment: getting Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @Max If you're referring to the snippet in the question I removed it as it wouldn't work as it relied on the OPs imagery. If you're referring to your own code then you need to include jquery.js in the page. I would also appreciate it if you removed your downvote.

Comment: this also helped me in php haha, my issue was that i was putting the     $loading.hide(); outside the setTimeout function